# Как реализовать слайдер который на картинки по середине?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, слайдер

Здравствуйте, вот картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите по середине квадратное, а сверху справа 2 ползунка направо и налево, как реализуются такие слайдеры?

Comment: Ползунки слева направо это Description, Features, Dimensions?

Comment: Я не знаю что это такое, думаю при клике на них должен меняться слайдер, только вот проблема почему тогда слева 1 маленькая картинка синего цвета, то есть при смене слайдера каждая должна быть синяя?

Comment: на этой картинке я вижу: 1) слайдер с превью картинок слева 2) табы справа

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!а

Comment: Пожалуйста напишите откуда взять слайдер с превью картинок слева, не могу найти

Comment: Например, slick.js.